# If statement giving a wrong answer

Tags: php

I've long used assignment inside long if statements to simplify things. But in this case, it's not working as intended. Here's what I've got:

```
$Employee = GetEmployeeName($Record['employee_id']);
echo 'First name: '.$Employee['first_name'];
echo 'Last name: '.$Employee['last_name'];
echo 'Record first name: '.$Record['first_name'];
echo 'Record last name: '.$Record['last_name'];

echo 'Comparing first name: ';
var_dump(strcasecmp($Employee['first_name'], $Record['first_name']));

echo 'Comparing last name: ';
var_dump(strcasecmp($Employee['last_name'], $Record['last_name']));

echo 'Comparing both together: ';
var_dump(strcasecmp($Employee['first_name'], $Record['first_name']) 
         || strcasecmp($Employee['last_name'], $Record['last_name']));

echo 'All together now: ';
var_dump($Foo = GetEmployeeName($Record['employee_id']) 
         && (strcasecmp($Foo['first_name'], $Record['first_name']) 
             || strcasecmp($Foo['last_name'], $Record['last_name'])));
```

Here's the results:

```
First name: ZACHARY
Last name: TAYLOR
Record first name: Zachary
Record last name: Taylor
Comparing first name: int(0)
Comparing last name: int(0)
Comparing both together: bool(false)
All together now: bool(true)
```

This makes no sense. Comparing the first name resolves as 0 (false); comparing the last name resolves as 0 (false); comparing them together resolves as false. Yet when I add the assignment into the if, it suddenly resolves as true. I've been assigning variables in ifs for a long time and I've never seen this happen. The weird thing is, if I assign outside the if, it works fine. So I could do that, but at this point it's about the principle of finding out what's going wrong so I can improve my knowledge of the language.

Assignment in this case gives true, as you can see by the fact that $Employee is populated. So, the final `var_dump` is essentially "true && false", which should resolve as false. Right?

Comment: No, the final `var_dump()` is dumping the value of `$Foo` only.

Comment: I suspect there is some type-casting trouble going on here.  Remember that strcasecmp() doesn't return bool, but rather an int.  What you should try is something like `(strcasecmp($Employee['first_name'], $Record['first_name'])==0)` so that you are converting the output of strcasecmp() to a bool value, appropriate for further comparison later.

Comment: I know it returns an int, but when they're equal it returns 0, which resolves as false. :)

Comment: No, he doesn't. :) testing for `strcasecmp($Employee['first_name'], $Record['first_name']) == 0` is the same as testing for `!strcasecmp($Employee['first_name'], $Record['first_name'])`, but without having to test for equality to zero. And when wrapped in an if, they both end up in the same way.

Comment: @Andrew, of course `(int) 0` is equivalent to `(bool) false` in PHP, and `(int) 1` is equivalent to `(bool) true`, but you should check on other integers.  I'm not sure if that applies.  I can't find the docs on it at the moment.  In any case, you should be explicitly defining what you want.  It will make your life easier... trust me.

Comment: All I want is to find out if they're the same. So I have no interest in this situation of checking on other integers.

Comment: @Andrew I have updated my answer with your logic from the above commet about !strcasecmp($Employee['first_name'], $Record['first_name']) being the same as strcasecmp($Employee['first_name'], $Record['first_name']) == 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The boolean operator `&&` has a higher [precedence](http://php.net/language.operators.precedence) than the assignment operator `=`. So this:

```
$Foo = GetEmployeeName($Record['employee_id']) 
     && (strcasecmp($Foo['first_name'], $Record['first_name']) 
         || strcasecmp($Foo['last_name'], $Record['last_name']))
```

Is equivalent to:

```
$Foo = (GetEmployeeName($Record['employee_id']) 
     && (strcasecmp($Foo['first_name'], $Record['first_name']) 
         || strcasecmp($Foo['last_name'], $Record['last_name'])))
```

Put the parentheses around the assignment and it works:

```
($Foo = GetEmployeeName($Record['employee_id'])) 
     && (strcasecmp($Foo['first_name'], $Record['first_name']) 
         || strcasecmp($Foo['last_name'], $Record['last_name']))
```

Comment: Son of a gumble. Check my question history; I've been stymied by the operator precedence before. But, according to the PHP documentation, "Although = has a lower precedence than most other operators, PHP will still allow expressions similar to the following: if (!$a = foo()), in which case the return value of foo() is put into $a. " What are the logical limits of this? They don't go into detail as to what expressions elevate ='s precedence.

Comment: @Gumbo I'm slightly confused as to why this doesn't evaluate as `$Foo = true && (false || false)`, which obviously returns false. Could you explain what I've missed here?

Comment: @lonesomeday: Due to the operator precedence (`&&` has a higher precedence than `=`, so the logical AND operation is evaluated before the assignment operation) the expression `$Foo = true && (false || false)` is equivalent to `$Foo = (true && (false || false))`.

Comment: But... `$Foo = (true && (false || false))` -> `$Foo = (true && false)` -> `$Foo = (false)`, so why is it dumping as `true`?

Comment: @Gumbo Quite -- and that returns `false`.

Comment: Either way, I went through my code and found one similar instance of me doing this (assigning then comparing) and ... it was wrapped in parentheses. So I've run into this problem before, it seems. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've just spent a fair while figuring out the problem with this, and have finally hit on the problem.

My test code:

```
var_dump($Foo = array('first_name' => 'ZACHARY', 'last_name' => 'TAYLOR') 
     && (strcasecmp($Foo['first_name'], 'Zachary') 
         || strcasecmp($Foo['last_name'], 'Taylor')));
```

Gives the output:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: Foo in /home/sam/test.php on line 6
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/lday/test.php:0
bool(true)
```

The problem is that `$Foo` is only assigned after *all* the action on the right of the `=` operator has happened.  So when you call `strcasecmp($Foo['first_name'], 'Zachary')`, you are actually doing `strcasecmp('', 'Zachary')`, which evaluates to `-7` (boolean `true`).  So your code evaluates like this:

```
$Foo = true && (-7 || -7);
```

Which is obviously true.

As shown elsewhere, the solution is to put `$Foo` in brackets, so it is evaluated first:

```
var_dump(($Foo = array('first_name' => 'ZACHARY', 'last_name' => 'TAYLOR'))  
     && (strcasecmp($Foo['first_name'], 'Zachary') 
         || strcasecmp($Foo['last_name'], 'Taylor')));
```

Comment: Aha! Thank you for figuring out what was confusing us above.

Answer (score 0):

because of the [operator precedence](https://www.php.net/language.operators.precedence), your code is interpreted as follows:

first, the result of:

```
GetEmployeeName($Record['employee_id']) && (strcasecmp($Foo['first_name'],
$Record['first_name']) || strcasecmp($Foo['last_name'],
$Record['last_name']))
```

if checked

after this the result is asignet to `$Foo` - and  `if` just checks if this assignment was successful.

to avoid this, use braces to group the parts of your camparision correctly.

Comment: For the sake of accuracy, `&&` has higher precedence than `==`, but `and` does not. [See the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Comment: @lonesomeday: thanks for the hint, i just saw that and rephrased my answer ;)

Answer (score -1):

[strcasecmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) :

> Returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than str2, and 0 if they are equal.

so the return of zero means they equal each other not false

// This is the example code form the PHP site itself

```
<?php
   $var1 = "Hello";
   $var2 = "hello";
   if (strcasecmp($var1, $var2) == 0) {
      echo '$var1 is equal to $var2 in a case-insensitive string comparison';
   }
?>
```

As you have stated in your comments above, these should both return the same results. Please execute the example code and you will see they do not.

```
<?php

if(strcasecmp("ZACHARY", "Zachary") == 0) {
    echo "We have a match with a zero (int) return\n"; // this returns 0
}

echo !strcasecmp("ZACHARY", "Zachary")."\n"; // this will return 1

?>
```

How you're using var_dump to compare int(0) returns will return a bool(false)

```
// returns int(0)
var_dump(strcasecmp("ZACHARY", "Zachary")); 

// will return bool(false) as it's comparing int(0) || int(0)
var_dump((strcasecmp("ZACHARY", "Zachary")) || (strcasecmp("ZACHARY", "Zachary")));
```

Comment: And 0 means false. Equal means false, in this case. But that's not what my question was about.

Comment: The PHP Documentation states that ZERO means the equal each other NOT FALSE

Comment: And the PHP Documentation also states that `(bool)0 === false`.

Comment: Right. It returns `(int)0`. And then I essentially do `if (0)`, which is false. I'm not sure what part of this you aren't getting. And none of this has any relevance to my question about why the last statement disagrees with the ones before, which apparently is due to operator precedence and not `strcasecmp`'s return value.

Comment: you're trying to compare the return int values as booleans and that's not going to give you the results you want

Comment: So thinking out loud, if strcasecmp returns a (int)0 if they match, how is that a false? They MATCH!!!

Comment: It does. I compare them in the 'comparing first name' and 'comparing last name' blocks. That returns `(int)0`. Good. I only want this to trigger then they aren't 0. Therefore, I do `if (strcasecmp())`, and if they aren't 0, that's true, and it triggers because they're different. So please don't tell me what results I'm going for, especially when my question didn't involve said results whatever.

Comment: Because otherwise, true would mean they match, and there'd be no way of telling how far apart they are. So they use integers to explain how far apart the two strings are, and 0 to indicate equal strings.

Comment: Urm. `var_dump(strcasecmp("ZACHARY", "Zachary") == 0);` returned `bool(true)`, and `var_dump(!strcasecmp("ZACHARY", "Zachary"));` returned... `bool(true)`. So where were they supposed to be different?

Comment: updating my answer again to reflect you var_dump logic